# Finding available memory slots in C#

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I was wondering how one would find the available memory slots vs taken slots on a motherboard in C#. With WMI I can find a total number of slots and also a list of memory sticks, but the information provided in both cases, specifically the latter, it's seemingly generic and changes depending on the motherboard.

Essentially I'm looking to create a list every slot on the board and which specific ones are taken and by what kind. I imagine this may be able to be done with WMI, but as said, I can't seem to get around the problem that "DeviceLocator" in Win32_PhysicalMemory is confusing and uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a combination of using the information provided by Win32_PhysicalMemory with information such as the "Manufacturer" and "Product" fields in Win32_BaseBoard to create a set of known slots and compare the "DeviceLocator" field in Win32_PhysicalMemory against it. Not ideal, but it's the only solution that seems apparent.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you wish to compare. The only attribute that seems to make any sense is SlotLayout on [Win32_BaseBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394072(v=vs.85).aspx) Class, anyway it always returns a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Using Win32, you should be able to call [GetSystemFirmwareTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724379%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve a specified firmware table from the firmware table provider (SMBIOS table). Though [Pinvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx) give nothing for this unmanaged entry, you perhaps can search this way. You may find some help in [System Management BIOS (SMBIOS)](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios) web site.

See this